# How to build a computer emulator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, emulation

I've built an Intel-syntax assembly parser in JavaScript. Now I want to do more:

Which steps should I take to emulate instructions, registers, cycles etc. of a 32-bit or 64-bit RISC microprocessor, RAM, ROM and VGA in JavaScript?

Comment: have you tried this? http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Comment: @ysrb: Yes, but his JavaScript code is obfuscated and he doesn't let to re-use codes.

Comment: [I posted about writing a Chip-8 emulator in JavaScript](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-chip-eight-emulator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a great example of that with source code: [Gameboy Emulation](http://imrannazar.com/GameBoy-Emulation-in-JavaScript%3a-The-CPU)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other JavaScript computer emulators (virtual machines):

- https://github.com/ozaki-r/arm-js
- https://github.com/ubercomp/jslm32
- https://github.com/s-macke/jor1k
- https://github.com/asmblah/jemul8
- https://github.com/codinguncut/jsbochs
- http://sourceforge.net/p/jsdosbox/home/Home/
- http://bellard.org/jslinux/
- http://jsmachines.net/ (PCjs)